# Oracle: SELECT with applied transform unless field is empty

Tags: sql, oracle, spatial

I have the following statement that I am trying to run against an Oracle table in order to get a set of results back to export:

```
SELECT 
   a.CLUSTER_ID, 
   SDO_CS.transform(a.CELL_GEOM, 4326).GET_WKT()  CELL_GEOM, 
   SDO_CS.transform(a.CELL_CENTROID, 4326).GET_WKT()  CELL_CENTROID, 
   SDO_CS.transform(a.CLUSTER_CENTROID, 4326).GET_WKT()  CLUSTER_CENTROID, 
   a.NUM_POINTS, 
   a.FEATURE_PK, 
   SDO_CS.transform(a.CLUSTER_EXTENT, 4326).GET_WKT()  CLUSTER_EXTENT
FROM HIGHWAYS.CLUSTER_128000M a
```

When I run this against my data set I get the following error:

```
ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_CS", line 2553
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_CS", line 2678
```

This is caused (I believe) by the fact that some of the fields may be empty in the database. How can I modify the code to take this into account and not attempt to apply the transform if the field is empty? Once the code has run I will be exporting to SQL Server and due to SQL Server being useless at transforms I am applying them in Oracle before copying the data across as it is stored in WGS84 (27700) in Oracle and I need it in 4326 when retrieving it later from SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT a.CLUSTER_ID,
       CASE
           WHEN a.CELL_GEOM IS NOT NULL THEN SDO_CS.transform(a.CELL_GEOM, 4326).GET_WKT()
           ELSE a.CELL_GEOM.GET_WKT()
       END CELL_GEOM,
       CASE
           WHEN a.CELL_CENTROID IS NOT NULL THEN SDO_CS.transform(a.CELL_CENTROID, 4326).GET_WKT()
           ELSE a.CELL_CENTROID.GET_WKT()
       END CELL_CENTROID,
       CASE
           WHEN a.CLUSTER_CENTROID IS NOT NULL THEN SDO_CS.transform(a.CLUSTER_CENTROID, 4326).GET_WKT()
           ELSE a.CLUSTER_CENTROID.GET_WKT()
       END CLUSTER_CENTROID,
       a.NUM_POINTS,
       a.FEATURE_PK,
       CASE
           WHEN a.CLUSTER_EXTENT IS NOT NULL THEN SDO_CS.transform(a.CLUSTER_EXTENT, 4326).GET_WKT()
           ELSE a.CLUSTER_EXTENT.GET_WKT()
       END CLUSTER_EXTENT
FROM HIGHWAYS.CLUSTER_128000M a
```

Comment: You solution was partly correct. If you can add the .GET_WKT() on the end of the geometry columns on the else clauses then I will accept it as the answer. If the GET_WKT() is not present then an error occurs whereby Oracle states it expected a clob and got a geometry. Thanks.